# Error CS0518 Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, .net, version

When building the C# (.NET 6) project with unit tests, I have found the error CS0518:

```
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
```

I was trying to add `using System.String`, to the file with the method causing the error, but without success.

Between other error messages, after rebuilding, I also found messages about version conflicts.

How to resolve this error message?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages about version conflicts were related to the upgrade of .NET in connected projects in the same solution. The main project, which was the system under test, `System.String` namespace has a greater version (.NET 8).

After adjusting the version of the test project the errors disappeared.